# How to get rid of fish oil stink on a dog?

Tags: dogs, diet, grooming

I gave my dog a cap of fish oil and now he reeks of fish. I don't even have to go anywhere near his mouth to smell it. I can smell it from the end of the leash and while I sit on the couch and him on the floor. Also, I made sure that the bottle of fish oil caps wasn't expired.

To those who give their dogs fish oil, does it really make them smell like that? He only had one cap and I didn't follow through anymore. Is this normal?

And ultimately, how do I get rid of this smell?

Answer (score 0):

We give our puppy a special milk^ with fish oil in, but luckily it doesn't smell... Therefore knowing if the caps should smell or not I don't know... So this advice is just from the point of view of bad breath and how to get rid of it.

You could try giving him a mint flavoured chew or treat. Again our pup has these on occasion and his breath is always fresher for a few hours afterwards.

More promisingly you could clean his teeth, even dog toothpastes are designed to break down bad smells cause by food and bacteria in the mouth. I'd think this would be the best way to clear the smell, think of your mouth after eating garlic and how cleaning your teeth works.

I assume he hasn't got any in his fur, but if he has around his mouth then again a cleaning wipe (I use pups tear stain wipes on his whole face as it's so small...) might remove it from that.

^*lactose minimalised puppy milk with fish oil and vitamins (from Pets at Home)*

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your tips. I think I need to look another source of fish oil for him. When I gave him the fish oil cap, I pushed it to the back of his tongue so it gets swallowed right away. I think the smell is coming from his throat so brushing his teeth and cleaning the fur around his mouth didn't really help. Hopefully I find a minty treats from pet stores where i live :)

Comment: Uhm... Is the fish oil recommended by a vet? If not, there is an easier solution...